# performance of many if statements/switch cases

Tags: performance, big-o

If I had literally 1000s of simple if statements or switch statements

ex:

```
if 'a':
  return 1
if 'b':
  return 2
if 'c':
  return 3
...
...
```

Would the performance of creating trivial if statements be faster when compared to searching a list for something? I imagined that because every if statement must be tested until the desired output is found (worst case O(n)) it would have the same performance if I were to search through a list. This is just an assumption. I have no evidence to prove this. I am curious to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially put these things in to delegates that are then in a map, the key of which is the input you've specified.

C# Example:

```
// declare a map.  The input(key) is a char, and we have a function that will return an
// integer based on that char.  The function may do something more complicated.
var map = new Dictionary<char, Func<char, int>>();

// Add some:
map['a'] = (c) => { return 1; };
map['b'] = (c) => { return 2; };
map['c'] = (c) => { return 3; };
// etc... ad infinitum.
```

Now that we have this map, we can quite cleanly return something based on the input

```
public int Test(char c)
{
    Func<char, int> func;
    if(map.TryGetValue(c, out func))
        return func(c);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, we can call Test and it will find the appropriate function to call (if present).  This approach is better (imho) than a list as you'd have to potentially search the entire list to find the desired input.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the language and the compiler/interpreter you use. In many interpreted languages, the performance will be the same, in other languages, the `switch` statements gives the compiler crucial additional information that it *can* use to optimize the code.

In C, for instance, I expect a long `switch` statement like the one you present to use a lookup table under the hood, avoiding explicit comparison with all the different values. With that, your `switch` decision takes the same time, no matter how many cases you have. A compiler might also hardcode a binary search for the matching case. These optimizations are typically not performed when evaluating a long `else if()` ladder.

In any case, I repeat, it depends on the interpreter/compiler: If your compiler optimized `else if()` ladders, but no switch statements, what it *could* do with a `switch` statement is quite irrelevant. However, for mainline languages, you should be able to expect all constructs to be optimized.

Apart from that, I advise to use a `switch` statement wherever applicable, it carries a lot more semantic information to the reader than an equivalent `else if()` ladder.